# Method to maintain a:visited links when using Ajax, jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery ajax to load content into my web page.

When a user clicks on a link, the href turns a different color to symbolize they have clicked that link. The problem, however, is when that ajax content is flushed from the page to load other content in, and then brought back, the href selections the user had previously made are no longer maintained.

I am looking for a way to keep track of which links the user has visited as they navigate the ajax website so that all `a:visited` links stay persistant.

The content is dynamic, served from an MySQL database.

Comment: How the DOM looks like? **What are you doing with the ajax response?** do you override the page\ elements in the page? what is `:visited` in `a:visited?`

Comment: Just insert to the DOM only new elements and don't override the old ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using ajax to load content, I'd assume the way to keep track if what was previously clicked is to simply use classes instead?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do some ajax stuff
    $(this).addClass('visited');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/VCGbF/3/)

If you are reloading content with ajax, and expecting visited links to be remembered, they won't be. You'll probably need to use cookies, local storage or keep track of what was clicked  on the server, like say in a session variable that is updated with the correct links in the same ajax call that is getting the content.

The question then is why you are reloading the content from the database, instead of just detaching and reattaching it when it already exists on the page.

Comment: I believe he has other problems. he's probably doing something woth with the ajax response.

Comment: This is more or less excatly what I have and that works. Let's call this Content A. But when a user loads Content B (which flushes Content A) and then goes back and loads Content A again, those href selections are no longer there.

Comment: To your edit >> edit >> Good question. I never considered detaching the content. Can I do that in jQuery or is that in PHP?

Comment: Yes, look at jQuery's [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), it keeps the event handlers etc. and lets you just keep the already loaded content in a variable, and then just put it back again later when someone clicks that same link, without reloading content that is already loaded once. You will need a function to check it the content is already loaded from the DB, but something simple like checking if a variable is defined or something will do that.